# Is PHP page display asynchronous

Tags: php, asynchronous

I am trying to create a project where I make an API request to another server and write down HTML interface with the data I get. For example, if a single request takes 2 seconds to complete and if there were 5 people that requested the same page, would the last person wait 2 seconds to finish or wait for other people to finish so 10 seconds? I couldn't find any info about this and not sure if Node is a better option for this project.

Comment: This should be easy enough to test with a simple `sleep(10)` and opening several browser tabs…

Comment: You would ideally use placeholder content, then fire off some ajax requests to fetch the other data elements, and then inject those in the page at the spots of the placeholders.

Comment: Don't quite understand your problem. Each user has its own session... So each user requesting the PHP-page would be served independently. Each user would have to wait 2 seconds for their request to finish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any normal web server + PHP setup will handle several requests in parallel. Each incoming request spawns a new web server thread with independent PHP instance. There are several different models of how this can be handled by a web server (workers, threads, events, etc.), but in general that's how it works. There's some limit to how many requests can be handled in parallel, but generally speaking it's *significantly more than one.*

So, modulus some overhead of running several PHP threads in parallel, each request will be handled in 2 seconds.

A typical pitfall here is session handling: if each PHP instance tries to get a handle on the same session data, they'll block since only one instance at a time can use the normal file-based session store, and subsequent requests will have to wait. To be clear: that's if the same user tries multiple parallel requests; it does not affect different users with different sessions. That goes for any shared resource you may be trying to access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to create test with this code 

`$start = microtime(true);
$integer = 5345345;
for ($x = 1; $x < 100000000; $x++) {
    $integer = $integer / $x;
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'It took ' . ($end - $start) . ' seconds!';`

It takes like 3 seconds. I tried opening it in multiple tabs but it always waits for the tab before to finish. I'm using XAMPP for testing and this is my apache settings

    `StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers      250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   5`

Comment: To update to above question, I found out that there is something like a "lock" for same client requests. I tried to open the same page with different devices and it worked perfectly.